# Tomcat7: Hot deployment using exploded war (like Grails)

Tags: tomcat, grails, hotdeploy

I'm trying to build a development environment for a Java/Spring web application in Tomcat.
I've recently used Grails and, as you can see, in Grails there is a file scanner that intercepts changes on Java/Groovy files and automatically, and hot deploys on Tomcat server.

I have looked at the Grails source code and I can see that it uses a Tomcat7 embedded server, but I can't understand how the hot deployment works.

It don't use the standard Tomcat7 context redeploy feature.

Someone knows how Grails hot deployment works?

Answer (score 1):

Grails use [Spring Loaded](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-loaded) as it's reload agent, you can look how it works.

There's also others similar questions in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring+reload